How can single thread execution speed further increase since frequency stagnates?
What are things that newer CPU can do to speed up single thread execution?

multiple registers? (can compilers always benefit from it?)

SIMD? (do compilers use SIMD without code annotation?)

does a larger cache always speed up execution speed?

Is branch prediction faster with more transistors?


What other things have been increasing execution speed?
A lot of "common algorithms" cannot be parallelized or use concurrency, but with newer CPUs, it still "feels" like single execution is faster than the increase in frequency.
How can CPU designers go around frequency limitations to increase single thread speed?
I don't really follow CPU designs, it looks quite complicated.

The simple answer here is "they don't".

Which "common algorithm" or rather "common problem" cannot be parallelized? There aren't many such problems AFAIK. We often don't parallelize them because what we have is fast enough, and parallelization isn't trivial. But that doesn't mean it cannot be done.

@freakish there are a lot of important algorithms that cannot be, which is what I mean. Those algorithms can be a bottleneck in a software execution.

@jokoon no, there are not "a lot" of them. I'm still waiting for an example of a single, commonly used algorithm that cannot be parallelized to a significant degree.

"I don't really follow CPU designs, it looks quite complicated." and yet you want to know about it by asking this question? Sounds like you didn't do your research.

@freakish I'm still waiting for an example of a single, commonly used algorithm that cannot be parallelized to a significant degree AES-CBC encryption.

@AndrewHenle AES-CBC decryption is parallelizable. And there are variations of CBC encryption that are parallelizable as well. But fair enough, this is one of those rare algorithms.

@freakish https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete

@AndrewHenle yeah, 99% of those examples are not "common algorithms", rather theoretical algorithms of little importance. And the rest can be replaced with parallelizable algorithms that do more or less the same.

@freakish So you just blindly dismiss even the possibility of non-parallelizable algorithms with statements like "can be replaced with parallelizable algorithms that do more or less the same", and when given an actual algorithm such as AES-CBC encryption that cannot be parallelized you just dismiss it out-of-hand by invoking other algorithms that are incompatible?  Zealotry is wonderful, I suppose.

@AndrewHenle I already commented on AES-CBC encryption. Yes, it cannot be parallelized, but it can be replaced with parallel variant: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26021/can-aes-in-cbc-mode-be-parallelized Not to mention that there are other parallelizable encryption algorithms. Why would I care about some algorithm if I can replace it with a parallel one? Look at my first comment: I'm actually talking about solutions to problems, not some algorithm. Algorithms and their implementation are not goals on their own.

And I'm not dismissing possibility of the existance of non-parallelizable, yet important problems. I'm simply challenging the claim that there are "a lot of them", which is just false. And I already agreed (at least partially) with you about AES-CBC. So I don't really understand your last comment.

CBC is intentionally designed to be strictly sequential. But if it is too slow to handle a 1GB file for example, you can easily chop up the data into 20 times 50MB and handle them in parallel.

@AndrewHenle Every algorithm is parallelisable by running 16 independent processes on 16 cores. Each of them can run AES-CBC independently. A processor with 16 cores can easily do 10 times as much work per time unit than a single thread, so single threaded performance is not very important overall. And there are 128 core ARM servers. If you run a single thread you are wasting the performance of 127 CPUs.

@gnasher729 no, that's not how CPUs work. “You can't produce a baby in one month by getting nine women pregnant.” Having more thread does not speed up one task unless you can divide that task.

An addition to the question was: Can CPU speed be increased for one thread only?
Clock speed is mostly limited by heat and power consumption. If you run two cores at half speed, you use much less power than with one core at full speed, so you want to use more cores.
But if you use a single thread only, that produces one eighth of the heat of eight cores at the same speed. If your code can’t use multiple cores, you can run that core at a higher speed. You can even move the thread to a different core say every second, so the heat goes to different places in the chip, allowing even more power usage = clock speed without the processor getting too hot.
So it’s easier to get more work done with a single thread. It is still much better (less heat, less power) to use multiple threads.
Do bigger caches produce more speed? Depends. First, with the same technology access to a larger cache can take longer. So it is a requirement to have better technology.
Some software is designed to use caches in an optimal way. If the processor has a bigger cache but the software makes incorrect assumptions, it might not use the bigger cache and it doesn’t help. You get the biggest benefit if the old processor didn’t have enough cache for a task, and now it is enough. For instruction caches, you can likely not influence the amount of cache needed. So either the smaller cache was big enough or you win.
Single threaded operation can have more speed gains. My computer has 8 cores, with 24MB L2 cache, with 12MB shared between a group of 4 cores. A single or two threads have 12MB cache for themselves. Eight threads share 12MB between four cores. Still, the eight cores will do an awful more work.


Single thread performance is still increasing. For example about 50% between M1 and M4.

Anything that is slowed down noticeably by using a single thread only, get used to using multiple threads. In most environments this is a very, very simple task.

Easy improvements are larger caches, more cache levels, better branch prediction, more execution units, bigger buffers for OOO execution. Sometimes execution times for complex instructions (division and square root) can be improved.

Improving the instruction set and ISA is possible, but requires at least recompiling. Like more registers, more and/or larger vector registers, adding instructions that are often used by a compiler, efficient atomic instructions etc.


Currently it is much easier to add more cores than increasing single threaded performance. For example there are ARM server chips with 64 or 128 not very fast cores, perfect to handle requests by dozens and dozens of users simultaneously at lowest power usage. The same work can be done much faster and with less energy using multiple cores. This will happen until a point is reached where more threads cannot be used in a useful way in many cases.

for number 2: but there are task cannot be multithreaded, or that cannot be sped up by multithreading

There are tasks where you have to work harder. For example, an h.264 decoder for 8k video in software may be too time consuming and the way it is defined it looks like it needs to be performed sequentially. It turns out it can be performed diagonal by diagonal.

@jokoon some of them consist of waiting, so async/await may help.

You use asynch/await to avoid wasting CPU time. You’d use that no matter what your single-core performance is.


multiple registers? (can compilers always benefit from it?)

Adding registers is an architectural change that require recompilation, so is quite rare. But it was done in the x86 -> x64 migration, and the APX proposal might increase the register count in the future. It also includes various other improvements that should give some benefit.

SIMD? (do compilers use SIMD without code annotation?)

They could, but automatic vectorization is rather difficult to do well without manual intervention, and many compilers do not bother.

does a larger cache always speed up execution speed?

No. Latency is also a very important, and larger caches often result in higher latency. The working set and access patterns of the application is also important. If everything fits in the cache already there will be no benefit.

Is branch prediction faster with more transistors?

A higher transistor budget can help improve branch prediction and therefore performance. But some branches are almost impossible to predict, and some can be predicted well with even a simple predictor. So results will vary.

How can CPU designers go around frequency limitations to increase single thread speed?

The vast majority of improvements are a result of improved parallelization, from implicit instruction level parallelism to the massive explicit parallelism of GPUs. Most workloads have plenty of possible parallelism to be exploited, both implicitly and explicitly.
This will likely continue, with CPUs keeping more and more instructions in flight, as well as improvements on the software side to better use the available resources. It will also favor software that can scale well. Much of the advancement in AI has been enabled by the availability fairly cheap GPUs as an example.

On ARM, a SIMD register is the exact same as two floating point register. So you can be just lucky sometimes that unrelated fp operations can use SIMD registers. And if you pick the registers then your chances are good. If you have a loop using two fp additions you can quite likely choose registers so you can use a SIMD instruction.
